# Matplotlib plot scale

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, statistics

I want to make a few tools to help to learn and teach basic statistic. One of them aims to help visualise z-score probability table:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
import scipy.stats as st

def draw_z_score(x, cond, mean, std, title,color='b'):
    y = st.norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
    z = x[cond]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.ylim(ymin=0)
    plt.xlim(xmin=-4.5, xmax=4.5)
    plt.fill_between(z, 0, st.norm.pdf(z, mean, std),color=color)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

def z_table_probabilty (z_score, z_score2=None, area='l'):
    normal = np.arange(-3.9, 3.9, 0.1)
    if area == 'l':
       Pz = round(st.norm.cdf(z_score), 4)
       draw_z_score(normal,normal<z_score,0,1,f'z = {z_score}   P(z)={Pz}')
    elif area == 'r':
       Pz = round(1 - st.norm.cdf(z_score), 4)
       draw_z_score(normal,normal>z_score,0,1,f'Z ={z_score}   P(1-z)={Pz}',color='r')
    elif area == 'tt' and z_score2 != None:
       z2 = max(z_score, z_score2)
       z = min(z_score, z_score2)
       Pz = round(st.norm.cdf(z2) - st.norm.cdf(z), 4)
       draw_z_score(normal,(normal<z2)&(normal>z),0, 1, f'z= {z} i z\'= {z2}    P(z\'-z)={Pz}', color='y')
```

Now, when I try:

```
z_table_probabilty(-0.9)
```

I have:

[z-score=-0.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUMLF.png)

Could someone tell my why z-score -0.9 is equal 1 on my plot?, and why the distances between x=4 and end of distribution tail, and x=-4 and end of other tail are different? The whole plot seems to be slightly moved.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks
MV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`normal = np.arange(-3.9, 3.9, 0.1)` creates an array from `-3.9` to `3.8`. The end point is not included. Hence you see the curve start at `-3.9` and end at `3.8`.

With `normal<z_score` you choose all the points in `normal` which are smaller than `z_score`. When `z_score=-0.9`, those points are from `-3.9` to `-1.0` because `-0.9` is not smaller than `-0.9`.

In total I would recommend defining `normal` a bit more dense. This would avoid the two problems. E.g.

```
normal = np.linspace(-3.9, 3.9, 391)
```

to create points in steps of `0.02` instead of `0.1`.